# Problema para cargar fuentes en Github Pages en App React

Tags: css, github-pages

He subido una [web hecha con React a Github pages](https://oricis.github.io/react__films/) y no me esta cargando las fuentes de una librería ([Semantic UI](https://react.semantic-ui.com/)) que esta importa desde el CSS. En local las carga pero NO una vez enviadas al repositorio.

El problema se ve con los iconos, si se entra a una página de detalle por ejemplo, hay un icono para los enlaces externos en la parte inferior:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que una vez subida se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para publicar la página tengo los ficheros en el [directorio 'docs' de la rama master](https://github.com/oricis/react__films/tree/master/docs). Cargo el CSS de la librería (Semantic UI) localmente y esta a su vez sus assets). Los assets estan subidos aparentemente en el lugar correcto, por ejemplo uno de los que falla es *icons.woff*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
 que el el inspector tiene la ruta:

```
https://oricis.github.io/react__films/static/css/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.woff
```

Este fichero si esta en el repo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Editado

Es un problema con las rutas, de como intento cargar los ficheros en el CSS. Dentro del CSS de la librería:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:Icons;
    src:url(./themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.eot);
    src:url(./themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),url(./themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.woff2) format('woff2'),url(./themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.woff) format('woff'),url(./themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.ttf) format('truetype'),url(./themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.svg#icons) format('svg');
     font-style:normal;
    font-weight:400;
    font-variant:normal;
    text-decoration:inherit;
    text-transform:none
}
```

Esta a su vez, se carga en el `head` del `index.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/css/semantic-ui.2.4.0.min.css">
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Solución

Finalmente, moví la carpeta *fonts* al directorio con el resto de los recursos, en este caso a 'static', con lo que la ruta donde se encuentra una fuente sería por ejemplo: `static/fonts/font.woff' y las imports quedarían:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:Icons;
    src:url(../fonts/icons.eot);
    src:url(../fonts/icons.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
        url(../fonts/icons.woff2) format('woff2'),
        url(../fonts/icons.woff) format('woff'),
        url(../fonts/icons.ttf) format('truetype'),
        url(../fonts/icons.svg#icons) format('svg');
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:400;
    font-variant:normal;
    text-decoration:inherit;
    text-transform:none
}
```

Funcionando en el ambiente de desarrollo y en producción.

Comment: ¡Enhorabuena por encontrar la respuesta a tu pregunta! Por favor, marca tu propia respuesta como aceptada por si a alguien le ocurre lo mismo

Comment: @Lucía gracias, creo que mañana puedo marcarla. Un saludo.