# ¿Rutas para cargar recursos locales en una web?

Tags: html, rutas

La pregunta surge a partir del siguiente hilo y su correspondiente respuesta: [Problema para cargar fuentes en Github Pages en App React](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/315369) y podría ser **¿Cuál es la diferencia entre cargar un recurso local con una barra o punto y barra?**
Es decir ¿por qué funciona una ruta como `./fonts/xxx.woff` en unas ocasiones y en otras sería necesario usar `/fonts/xxx.woff` o incluso `fonts/xxx.woff`?

*Tengo alguna idea de que ocurre en uno y otro caso, pero siempre pruebo hasta que una funciona.*

Answer (score 4):

La diferencia en cada caso está en la forma como le dices al sistema que busque los recursos. Las tres expresiones pueden llegar a ser equivalentes si la implementación que hace uso del recurso, las usa de una u otra forma. Depende de en dónde las uses.

- `./fonts/xxx.woff` hace que la aplicación busque partiendo del directorio actual de ejecución (del script PHP, de la página, del proceso en el OS) y, desde allí, buscar el subdirectorio fonts y cargar el recurso xxx.woff
- `/fonts/xxx.woff`, dependiendo de la aplicación y la lógica detrás del llamado, puede ser una ruta absoluta en sistemas Unix (que para usuarios limitados a ver sólo cierto subdirectorio /var/www/html, podría ser equivalente a lo anterior). Si la aplicación concatena un directorio raíz a todas las rutas que le des, entonces se comportará parecido al anterior.
- `fonts/xxx.woff` deja a libre albedrío de la aplicación decidir el directorio desde el que comienza a buscar este recurso. Un ejemplo son las aplicaciones Java basadas en servlets (casi todas), que tienen un *contexto* (http://algo/tuApp y tuApp es el contexto) y todas las rutas siempre serán relativas a este contexto **a menos que implementes lógica adicional en tu servlet**.

Ahora bien, para un html común y corriente, servido por un servidor HTTP, las diferencias son más simples.

- `./fonts/xxx.woff` hace que la aplicación busque partiendo del directorio donde está el HTML y, desde allí, buscar el subdirectorio fonts y cargar el recurso xxx.woff
- `/fonts/xxx.woff` buscará desde la carpeta raíz que está sirviendo el servidor HTTP y buscará la carpeta fonts. Si no tienes permisos, te dará HTTP 403; si no existe, 404.
- `fonts/xxx.woff` no tiene mucho sentido porque te quedaría una URL del tipo http://algo**fonts/xxx.woff**.